# How to position nodes at same level with ELK(Eclipse Layout Kernel) graph

Tags: json, graph, nodes

I am trying to build a graph using ELK (https://www.eclipse.org/elk/). Everything is working great but I have one small issue.
I don't know how to position these two nodes marked on red at the same level.

[image: graph issue]

This is my JSON which I am using to create this tree and it can be tested here: https://rtsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/elklive/json.html but I don't know which option from documentation (if any) will resolve this issue.

```
{
   "children":[
   {
               "id":"42926",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":216
            },
            {
               "id":"42930",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":48
            },
            {
               "id":"42942",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":172
            },
            {
               "id":"42920",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":68
            },
            {
               "id":"42945",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":48
            },
            {
               "id":"42958",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":71
            },
            {
               "id":"43735",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":48
            },
            {
               "id":"43719",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":164
            },
            {
               "id":"43720",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":48
            },
            {
               "id":"43739",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":480,
               "height":307
            },
            {
               "id":"43742",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":68
            },
            {
               "id":"43744",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":51
            },
            {
               "id":"42975",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":68
            },
            {
               "id":"43015",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":88
            },
            {
               "id":"43013",
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "width":200,
               "height":68
            }
   ],
   "edges":[
  
      {
         "id":"42920_42926",
         "source":"42920",
         "target":"42926"
      },
      {
         "id":"42920_42942",
         "source":"42920",
         "target":"42942"
      },
      {
         "id":"42920_42958",
         "source":"42920",
         "target":"42958"
      },
      {
         "id":"42920_43719",
         "source":"42920",
         "target":"43719"
      },
      {
         "id":"42926_42930",
         "source":"42926",
         "target":"42930"
      },
      {
         "id":"42942_42945",
         "source":"42942",
         "target":"42945"
      },
      {
         "id":"42958_43735",
         "source":"42958",
         "target":"43735"
      },
      {
         "id":"43719_43720",
         "source":"43719",
         "target":"43720"
      },
      {
         "id":"43739_43742",
         "source":"43739",
         "target":"43742"
      },
      {
         "id":"43739_43013",
         "source":"43739",
         "target":"43013"
      },
      {
         "id":"43742_43744",
         "source":"43742",
         "target":"43744"
      },
      {
         "id":"43744_42926",
         "source":"43744",
         "target":"42926"
      },
      {
         "id":"43744_42942",
         "source":"43744",
         "target":"42942"
      },
      {
         "id":"43744_42958",
         "source":"43744",
         "target":"42958"
      },
      {
         "id":"43744_43719",
         "source":"43744",
         "target":"43719"
      },
      {
         "id":"42975_43739",
         "source":"42975",
         "target":"43739"
      },
      {
         "id":"43013_43015",
         "source":"43013",
         "target":"43015"
      },
    
   ],
   "id":"root",
   "layoutOptions":{
      "elk.algorithm":"layered",
      "elk.direction":"DOWN",
      "elk.hierarchyHandling":"INCLUDE_CHILDREN",
      "elk.layered.spacing.edgeNodeBetweenLayers":40,
      "elk.layered.nodePlacement.bk.fixedAlignment":"BALANCED"
   }
}
```

**Edit: Issue fixed [here](https://github.com/eclipse/elk/issues/504)**

Answer (score 2):

I played around with this a little bit and I think you need to apply

```
layering.layerConstraint: FIRST
```

on the node you want pulled up

OR

you can set the layer strategy for the entire graph to

```
org.eclipse.elk.layered.layering.strategy: INTERACTIVE
```

Comment: Hey @Wasi Haider, guys responsible for elk fixed this [here](https://github.com/eclipse/elk/issues/504)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the follow up.